# Alternative way to threads under Android

Tags: android, multithreading, parallel-processing, actor, coroutine

Android's Java and Oracle's Java are slightly different. Is it possible to use the following  actors or coroutines

- http://code.google.com/p/jetlang/
- http://incubator.apache.org/s4/
- http://www.malhar.net/sriram/kilim/
- http://code.google.com/p/coroutines/

also for Android in order to avoid to use threads and share more code between Android's Java and Oracle's Java? Are there other frameworks available for both Java versions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: By "alternative to threads" do you mean alternative to the `Thread` class or threading in general?

Comment: I would like to avoid to sync Threads or dead locks and would like to have something like an Actor model or coroutines also for Android. Is there anything out there for Android?

Answer (score 4):

You should try actors from Java version of Akka:
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/untyped-actors.html

It allows easy growing of actor topology using best practices (no direct access to actors by Java reference, limiting failures to zones, limiting overload using scheduler zones etc.) - all of them are described in free copy of "Scala in Depth" book:
http://typesafe.com/resources/scala-in-depth

Here is example (with demo http://vimeo.com/20303656) of dynamic behavior of actors using Akka FSM on Android:
https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-samples/akka-sample-fsm/src/main/scala/DiningHakkersOnBecome.scala

Also you can try lightweight actors from Functional Java:
https://github.com/functionaljava/functionaljava/blob/master/core/src/main/java/fj/control/parallel/Actor.java

Most minimalistic version of an actor for JVM is here:
https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/github/gist/viktorklang/Actor.scala
(its features described here: [How to implement actor model without Akka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657970/how-to-implement-actor-model-without-akka/27661385#27661385) )

Comment: Thank you. Akka depends on Scala runtime library which is more than 8 Mb. Gpars http://www.gpars.org/guide/guide/2.%20Getting%20Started.html#2.7%20Java%20API%20-%20Using%20GPars%20from%20Java is only 450 KB big. j-javaactors http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-javaactors/ is around 400 KB big. There is also http://code.google.com/p/functionaljava/downloads/list around 2 MB big and http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained