# How to implement actor model without Akka?

Tags: scala, concurrency, akka, actor

How to implement simple actors without Akka? I don't need high-performance for many (non-fixed count) actor instances, green-threads, IoC (lifecycle, Props-based factories, ActorRef's), supervising, backpressure etc. Need only sequentiality (queue) + handler + state + message passing.

As a side-effect I actually need small actor-based pipeline (with recursive links) + some parallell actors to optimize the [DSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signal_processing) algorithm calculation. It will be inside library without transitive dependencies, so I don't want (and can't as it's a jar-plugin) to push user to create and pass `akkaSystem`, the library should have as simple and lightweight interface as possible. I don't need IoC as it's just a library (set of functions), not a framework - so it has more algorithmic complexity than structural. However, I see actors as a good instrument for describing protocols and I actually can decompose the algorithm to small amount of asynchronously interacting entities, so it fits to my needs.

*Why not Akka*

Akka is heavy, which means that:

- it's an external dependency;
- has complex interface and implementation;
- non-transparent for library's user, for example - all instances are managed by akka's IoC, so there is no guarantee that one logical actor is always maintained by same instance, restart will create a new one;
- requires additional support for migration which is comparable with scala's migration support itself.
- It also might be harder to debug akka's green threads using `jstack`/`jconsole`/`jvisualvm`, as one actor may act on any thread.

Sure, Akka's jar (1.9Mb) and memory consumption (2.5 million actors per GB) aren't heavy at all, so you can run it even on Android. But it's also known that you  should  use specialized tools to watch and analyze actors (like Typesafe Activator/Console), which user may not be familiar with (and I wouldn't push them to learn it). It's all fine for enterprise project as it almost always has IoC, some set of specialized tools and continuous migration, but this isn't good approach for a simple library.

P.S. About dependencies. I don't have them and I don't want to add any (I'm even avoiding the scalaz, which actually fits here a little bit), as it will lead to heavy maintenance - I'll have to keep my simple library up-to-date with Akka.

Comment: What is the reason you don't want to use Akka?

Comment: It's more conceptual question. I understand that akka solves most typical problems, but Akka is heavy (not much of course), and you don't always need a new dependency in your project - for example if you have to do something very simple, based on actor conception (without high loading etc.)

Comment: Akka is not heavy

Comment: I'm talking about concept - you should create actorSystem (which is heavy). use Props to get actor from IoC-container (for decoupling) etc. etc. I know that IoD is important - but there is some cases when you don't need that, at least on first stages)

Comment: OK. Have a look at Actor implementation from "FP in Scala" book: https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/parallelism/Actor.scala

Comment: Akka is analog of EJB in JavaEE world (not such conceptual, but more practical), so it's also a big IoC-container, which you don't always need. I hope it will remain lightweight, but there is no guarantee

Comment: thanks. i've written one based on futures. Maybe it will help somebody!

Comment: Not sure why you are calling Akka an IoC container. It's not. The fact that it wraps `Actor`s in `ActorRef`s is just an implementation detail which simplifies lifecycle management and network transparency, but it does not "invert the control" even a bit.

Comment: just look at - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control, actually it is a key difference between library and framework: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA

Comment: @Vladimir Matveev O_o? IoC (in general sense not just IoD or DI) - is actually calling client-code from library-code. 1) Akka maintains Actor's lifecycle by reinstantiating them, 2) `system.actorOf` - is a factory which manages their creating (Service Locator), 3) even calling `receive` from dispatcher is a kind of IoC. 4) `ActorRef` is invented primarily because you can't inject actors with circular dependencies, so it's a part of IoD (secondary because of network abstraction)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is most minimal and efficient actor in the JVM world with API based on Minimalist Scala actor from Viktor Klang:
https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/blob/41eea0277530f86e4f9557b451c7e34345557ce3/src/test/scala/com/github/gist/viktorklang/Actor.scala

It is handy and safe in usage but isn't type safe in message receiving and cannot send messages between processes or hosts.

Main features:

- simplest FSM-like API with just 3 states (`Stay`, `Become` and `Die`): https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/blob/41eea0277530f86e4f9557b451c7e34345557ce3/src/test/scala/com/github/gist/viktorklang/Actor.scala#L28-L30
- minimalistic error handling - just proper forwading to the default exception handler of executor threads: https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/blob/41eea0277530f86e4f9557b451c7e34345557ce3/src/test/scala/com/github/gist/viktorklang/Actor.scala#L52-L53
- fast async initialization that takes ~200 ns to complete, so no need for additional futures/actors for time consuming actor initialization: https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/blob/41eea0277530f86e4f9557b451c7e34345557ce3/out0.txt#L447
- smallest memory footprint, that is ~40 bytes in a passive state (BTW the `new String()` spends the same amout of bytes in the JVM heap): https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/blob/41eea0277530f86e4f9557b451c7e34345557ce3/out0.txt#L449
- very efficient in message processing with throughput ~90M msg/sec for 4 core CPU: https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/blob/41eea0277530f86e4f9557b451c7e34345557ce3/out0.txt#L466
- very efficient in message sending/receiving with latency ~100 ns: https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/blob/41eea0277530f86e4f9557b451c7e34345557ce3/out0.txt#L472
- per actor tuning of fairness by the batch parameter: https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/blob/41eea0277530f86e4f9557b451c7e34345557ce3/src/test/scala/com/github/gist/viktorklang/Actor.scala#L32

Example of stateful counter:

```
  def process(self: Address, msg: Any, state: Int): Effect = if (state > 0) { 
     println(msg + " " + state)
     self ! msg
     Become { msg => 
        process(self, msg, state - 1)
     }
  } else Die

  val actor = Actor(self => msg => process(self, msg, 5))
```

Results:

```
scala> actor ! "a"
a 5

scala> a 4
a 3
a 2
a 1
```

Comment: you mean `if(!mbox.isEmpty && on.compareAndSet(0, 1)) ` (as `null` returned only only if queue is empty)? So, queue may became empty between `&&`.

Comment: maybe you can just add additional `mbox.isEmpty` check after `on.compareAndSet` before `poll`, or just check result of `poll` for `null`?

Comment: lazySet reminds me https://qconsf.com/sf2012/dl/qcon-sanfran-2012/slides/MartinThompson_LockFreeAlgorithmsForUltimatePerformanceMOVEDTOBALLROOMA.pdf

Comment: so queue of atomic references is faster than ConcurrentLinkedQueue. You may also try to replace Runnables with Future to be more scala-like (at least to see how much futures are slower). Concurrency is nice: if I understand correctly, when let's say 3 different threads do "!" - one receives null, 2nd will set n to the h, 3rd  will set to n the updated h, so chain will be correct; CAS on receiver guarantees correct pull, and `next = next` compensates non-atomic create-update (in "!"), so you can even use non-volatile `lazySet`. Cool! :)

Comment: I've quickly written some naive array-based queue implementation (aka Disruptor's ring, but unbounded by default) - https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/pull/8. Just to see is it really faster to use arrays (which I doubt) for buffering as LMAX says.

Comment: Please don't use naive approach to beat mechanical sympathy. If you are interested in other queue implementations then before writing your own solution, please, do test of following winners: https://github.com/JCTools/JCTools/tree/master/jctools-core/src/main/java/org/jctools/queues (and https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue if you are going send messages between different JVMs).

Answer (score 5):

This will use FixedThreadPool (and so its internal task queue):

```
import scala.concurrent._

trait Actor[T] {
  implicit val context = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1))
  def receive: T => Unit
  def !(m: T) = Future { receive(m) }
}
```

FixedThreadPool with size 1 guarantees sequentiality here. Of course it's NOT the best way to manage your threads if you need 100500 dynamically created actors, but it's fine if you need some fixed amount of actors per application to implement your protocol.

Usage:

```
class Ping(pong: => Actor[Int])  extends Actor[Int] {     
      def receive = {
          case m: Int => 
             println(m)
             if (m > 0) pong ! (m - 1)
      }    
}

object System { 
      lazy val ping: Actor[Int] = new Ping(pong) //be careful with lazy vals mutual links between different systems (objects); that's why people prefer ActorRef
      lazy val pong: Actor[Int] = new Ping(ping)
}

System.ping ! 5
```

Results:

```
import scala.concurrent._
defined trait Actor
defined class Ping
defined object System
res17: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@6be61f2c
5
4
3
2
1
0

scala> System.ping ! 5; System.ping ! 7
5
7
4
6
3
5
2
res19: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@54b053b1
4
1
3
0
2
1
0
```

This implementation is using two Java threads, so it's "twice" faster than counting without parallelization.

Comment: Have you tested this for "100500 dynamically created actors" ?

Comment: No. and won't as 100500 dynamically created actors is not what i'm looking for (as i explicitly specified in the question). Just imagine that you have an akka's fixedSize router here.

Comment: theoretical actor's conception has nothing to do with 100500 lightweight instances executed in lightweight threads, especially in my case

Comment: okay understood. What if your `Future` fails ? That can happen even with a small number of actors. Correct ?

Comment: you're talking with me like with child :) - it (reason of failure) will cause exception and i should catch it in my receive-method or it will be just ignored (ignored by wrapping Future). As i said - it's not enterprise, so i don't need lifecycle and supervising here. Most of my actors actually have no state and used only for piping. If i don't get my result from actors after timeout (library is blocking for outside world) - i will resend the data

Comment: failure management is not a part of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model, it's a part of Akka.

Comment: Thanks!  MaxThroughPut includes actor's initialization (which is slow here as it creates new pool everytime). Memory consumption is also big because of same reason (but i have small amount of actors). Multi-sending/Single-sending are indicative and pretty much fine for my task  - as i said no-need for high performance (finally, i can implment some performance-requiring map/reduce operation's with parallell collections)

Comment: Enqueue/Dequeue seems pretty slow, maybe changing queue implementation (for thread-pool) can make it a little faster.

Comment: Main problem of this implementaion of actors is that it works only with thread pools baked by single thread.

Comment: only when "you need 100500 dynamically created actors" :). Long time ago i used similar solution for coordination inside our simple container - i had only few application-scoped services (count of services was restricted by business&technical requirements), so created few such actors to avoid `synchronized` - worked pretty well!