# How to model actor with mutable collection inside?

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor which has a fairly complex state, but let's say it's a list. I've come up with the following example:

```
class Account
class Bank extends Actor {
  var accounts = List[Account]()
  def receive = {
    case x: Account =>
      accounts ++= List(x)
      println(accounts.length)
    case _ => 
  }
}
```

basically I want this actor to wrap the List, and I want to be able to add to that collection via:

```
val system = ActorSystem("banks")
val bankActor = system.actorOf(Props[Bank], name = "mybank")
bankActor ! new Account
```

Am i writing this actor even close to being optimal and safe? Is there a better way, without introducing a var?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there a better way, without introducing a var?

It is perfectly okay to have mutable state (vars) inside an Actor. In fact, that is the primary use case of having actors. Actor's mutable state is thread safe with a few exceptions. The primary being you shouldn't `close over` the mutual inside a `Future` in the actor's receive method.

Comment: Although I agree with you, I prefer to embed this mutable state into some class with some method "update" or equivalent interface. This eases my life most of the times, especially when working with even-sourcing models and akka-persistence.

Answer (score 5):

I agree that using a `var` in an `Actor` is fine.

As an alternative, here's another approach using `become` that avoids the `var`.

```
class Bank extends Actor {
  def receive = receiveAccounts(List.empty)

  def receiveAccounts(accounts: List[Account]): Receive = {
    case x: Account =>
      println(accounts.length + 1)
      context.become(receiveAccounts(x :: accounts))

    case _ =>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to follow FP without vars and mutable data structures in your actors when use [Akka FSM transitions](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/fsm.html#A_Simple_Example) or approach from [the Minimalist Scala Actor](https://gist.github.com/viktorklang/2362563) presented by Viktor Klang year ago. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657970/how-to-implement-actor-model-without-akka/27661385#27661385) is an example of counter that counts down using this approach.