# Atomic function/method in scala (without introducing actor system overheads)

Tags: scala, akka

I currently use an Akka actor to establish a code block that is executed atomically and in a thread safe manner (Akka mailbox semantics impose atomicity by virtue of processing one message at a time).

However this introduces the need for an actor system, and additional side-effects or bloat (having to manually propagate exceptions to the caller, losing type safety on `ask`, and in general using message semantics rather than function calls).

Can a thread-safe atomic code block be accomplished in scala in a simpler way? would you apply `@volatile` to a function?

Comment: can you please provide example what you trying to achieve? Is your function cannot be accessed more than 1 thread? Function should be thread safe as long as it do not rely on external state, and operates only with immutable parameters.

Comment: I guess one ends up reimplementing actors :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what kind of shared state you want to protect here:

- The easiest and universal choice is using same old `synchronized`. However, unlike the Akka, it's completely blocking, so may easily kill your performance and of course the code-style, as it's hard to control messy side effects. It may also allow for [dead-locks](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075692/java-concurrency/avoid-synchronization-deadlocks.html).
- Java's [locks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) is same approach, but might be a little better for performance.
- Another option is same old Java's `AtomicReference`(implements CAS operations) and related classes. The positive thing about is that they're non-blocking - developers actually use them to build high-performant collections. The ways of using locks and CAS are decribed [here](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/concurrency.html). They both are pretty low-level mechanizms, so I would not recommend to use them much, especially for business-logic (any actor's implementation would be better).
- If your shared state is a collection - you may want use same old Java's concurrent collections (they have atomic operations like `putIfAbscent`). Scala has interesting non-blocking [TrieMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.4/index.html#scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap) for instance.
- [Scala STM](http://nbronson.github.io/scala-stm/) is also an alternative
- Finally, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657970/how-to-implement-actor-model-without-akka) is dedicated to lightweight actor model implementations.

P.S. Volatile annotation is nothing more than [`volatile`](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile) keyword analog from Java. You can put it on the method just because any annotation can be put on anything.

Comment: Thanks @dk14 for the good alternatives. I especially like the suggestions for `synchronized` and `TrieMap`.  I believe that a synchronized block will not be "blocking" if implemented inside a future (or if it's a pure computation), which I think it can, just like any other code block.

Comment: synchronized block **will** be blocking inside future as well - even inside the actor, so I'd not recommend it.

Comment: maybe I was dubious about the misnomer "synchronized block" in my comment.. I just meant a block of code, not blocking code. Otherwise I'm not sure why a synchronized function is "blocking" by nature. Do you mean that in case it needs to wait because another caller is inside the synchronized function, then it completely blocks the waiting caller?

Comment: yes, I mean waiting for another caller exits critical section. It blocks current thread and as @Chirlo said may [cause deadlocks](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075692/java-concurrency/avoid-synchronization-deadlocks.html). And more than that, it may cause long-time locks if you're doingsome io calls there - so future won't compensate it: `Future{ object.synchronized{ longTimeIoCall()}}` is useless if you want to parallell several `longTimeIoCall`'s.

Comment: On second point you say 'I would recommend to use them much', I guess you mean 'I wouldn't' , is that right?

Comment: Just to note actors would probably timeout rather than deadlock. E.g. if actor A messages actor B that messages actor A when processing the message received from A (or a cycle from A to B containing additional actors).

Comment: if you use `synchronized` or any blocking code (like `Await.result`) inside actors - they may deadlock as well. `receive` is just a handler which can be blocked by anything. In case of unbounded mailbox - cycles will probably cause "100 % CPU" and may cause OutOfMemory if processing is slow enough. In case of bounded mailbox you may gota deadlock instead of "100 % CPU". Timeout will work only with `ask pattern` explicitly used.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, the simplest might be old `synchronized`:

```
//your mutable state
 private var x = 0

//better than locking on 'this' is to have a dedicated lock
private val lock = new Object

def add(i:Int) = lock.synchronized { x += i }
```

This is the 'old Java' way, but it might work for you depending on what you're doing. Of course, **this is the fastest way to deadlocks** if your synchronize operation is more complex and/or you need high throughput.

Comment: I wonder if `@volatile def add(i:Int) = { doStuff() }` does the same. oddly enough, it seems to compile.

Comment: it compiles because annotations may be put on anything, but it does nothing actually because volatile is nothing more than [`volatile`](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html#volatile) keyword analog from Java.

Comment: Thanks once again, this is probably the most straightforwardly good solution for my question, at the cost of being blocking. As long as the application avoids deadlocks by scantily employing this. (For bulk usage of atomic operations in an app, I'd look at the options in the other answer and of course or Akka, which are less simple but possibly scale better). Blocking on quick nascent no IO code is hardly really what we mean by blocking.

Comment: For adding an item to a `scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer` while being thread-safe, this is probably perfect. Thanks again.