# Implement Actor model without Akka in Scala

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am doing my small research that implement Actor without Akka
I found one implementation of Actor in Scala. ([How to implement actor model without Akka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27657970/how-to-implement-actor-model-without-akka))

It's very simple. Because I have not enough reputation to add the comment, so I create this question.
I wonder if I use Actor like below.

1/ How can I shutdown that actor from main thread?

2/ How can I add feature similar to Akka, like parent actor, kill request, and become method?

```
import scala.concurrent._

trait Actor[T] {
      implicit val context = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1))
      def receive: T => Unit
      def !(m: T) = Future { receive(m) }
}
```

This is my own example when trying to adapt the above code snippet

```
import scala.concurrent._

/**
  * Created by hminle on 10/21/2016.
  */
trait Message
case class HelloMessage(hello: String) extends Message
case class GoodByeMessage(goodBye: String) extends Message

object State extends Enumeration {
  type State = Value
  val Waiting, Running, Terminating = Value
}

trait Actor[T] {
  implicit val context = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1))
  private var state: State.State = State.Waiting
  def handleMessage: T => Unit ={
    if(state == State.Waiting) handleMessageWhenWaiting
    else if(state == State.Running) handleMessageWhenRunning
    else handleMessageWhenTerminating
  }
  def !(m: T) = Future {handleMessage(m)}
  def handleMessageWhenWaiting: T => Unit
  def handleMessageWhenRunning: T => Unit
  def handleMessageWhenTerminating: T => Unit
  def transitionTo(destinationState: State.State): Unit = {
    this.state = destinationState
  }
}

class Component1 extends Actor[Message]{
  def handleMessageWhenRunning = {
    case HelloMessage(hello) => {
      println(Thread.currentThread().getName + hello)
    }
    case GoodByeMessage(goodBye) => {
      println(Thread.currentThread().getName + goodBye)
      transitionTo(State.Terminating)
    }
  }

  def handleMessageWhenWaiting = {
    case m => {
      println(Thread.currentThread().getName + " I am waiting, I am not ready to run")
      transitionTo(State.Running)
    }
  }

  def handleMessageWhenTerminating = {
    case m => {
      println(Thread.currentThread().getName + " I am terminating, I cannot handle any message")
      //need to shutdown here
    }
  }

}
class Component2(component1: Actor[Message]) extends Actor[Message]{
  def handleMessageWhenRunning = {
    case HelloMessage(hello) => {
      println(Thread.currentThread().getName + hello)
      component1 ! HelloMessage("hello 1")
    }
    case GoodByeMessage(goodBye) => {
      println(Thread.currentThread().getName + goodBye)
      component1 ! GoodByeMessage("goodbye 1")
      transitionTo(State.Terminating)
    }
  }

  def handleMessageWhenWaiting = {
    case m => {
      println(Thread.currentThread().getName + " I am waiting, I am not ready to run")
      transitionTo(State.Running)
    }
  }

  def handleMessageWhenTerminating = {
    case m => {
      println(Thread.currentThread().getName + " I am terminating, I cannot handle any message")
      //need to shutdown here
    }
  }
}
object ActorExample extends App {
  val a = new Component1
  val b = new Component2(a)
  b ! HelloMessage("hello World 2")
  b ! HelloMessage("hello World 2, 2nd")
  b ! GoodByeMessage("Good bye 2")
  println(Thread.currentThread().getName)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at `Actor model` implementation in `scalaz`and take ideas from it, source code in [scalaz actor](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/tree/series/7.3.x/concurrent/src/main/scala/scalaz/concurrent) is easier for insight than `akka`. You have freedom of choice about architecture: you can use mailboxes based on ConcurrentLinkedQueue like in Akka, use CAS for AtomicReffernce like in scalaz, in your case you use Future mechanism. IMO, you must write a context of your actor system, so solve first and second items in your question it's the variant of ActorContext:

```
val contextStack = new ThreadLocal[List[ActorContext]]
```

and shutdown can look like this:

1.

```
case Kill                       ⇒ throw new ActorKilledException("Kill")
case PoisonPill                 ⇒ self.stop()
```

2. For storing parent actor and similar task, you must store reference on them:

```
def parent: ActorRef
```

it's hard to say about advantages of every technique (CAS, mailboxes), it's possible variants to your research.